# How to connect SQL Server back to .NET project

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, database

To give a bit of context, I was assigned to be a maintainer for a website developed with .NET framework, we lost contact with previous developer. That said, I'm a bit new to the .NET world and will need a bit of time to adapt, one thing is left to figure out how to connect the SQL Server database back to the project (it is hosted locally on the company server), and I still don't know what SQL Server type they are using.

I tried locating some clues in the `web.config` file but didn't come to any conclusion:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Also in the web.config i have the following (removed information for security reasons):

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="" connectionString="data source=MSI;initial catalog=MelkiDBbranch1;user id=;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Along with a really long Entity Framework file which is SQL related, I will access the local server soon but I need to have a general idea on what I should look for in order to establish the connection on my PC

Comment: Could be in appsettings.json, in environment variables

Comment: In Web.config you should have a section called "ConnectionStrings" and one entry under that section has the information to connect to the database See https://connectionstrings.com

Comment: Check in your code where you are making a connection. That would likely be in your  DbContext constructor (.config files might have connection data that is never used) .

Comment: Based on this, it _might_ be LocalDB, which is the successor to SQL Server Compact Edition that instead uses the full SQL Server engine rather than Compact's smaller in-process engine. It's similar to SQL Server Express Edition, but designed to deploy with the client application and run on the same computer, such that it can start up/shut down as needed. Personally, for a web site, if LocalDB was good enough I'd have gone with Express Edition in the first place, but again: the LocalDB text in the config here could just be a red herring.

Comment: I have added connectionStrings i found in web.config file (i still can't reply to comments)

Answer (score 1):

We have this connection string:

```
data source=MSI;initial catalog=MelkiDBbranch1;user id=;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework
```

This connection string tells us the server name is `MSI`, and the database name on that server is `MelkiDBbranch1` (since one server can host *many* databases). I expect the user id and password are redacted, and you can see actual values in the real string.

To connect to this server you need to make sure the `MSI` name resolves on your network (there's probably a default dns suffix). If you're using [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), you can then connect to a database engine using the `MSI` name for the server, with SQL Server Authentication selected and using the login/password from the connection string.

If you expand the "Options" section there should also be a place to choose the database, but this is optional.

[image: SQL Server Management Studio new connection dialog]

Finally, depending on the network and firewall configurations, you can probably do this with Management Studio installed on your own computer, without needing to first login to the server.